# Move dimensions to original order after apply_ufunc in xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray

My dataset has 3 dimensions in the order `(time, y, x)` and I use `apply_ufunc` to apply a computation along the `time` dimension. This rearranges the order of the dimensions as `(y, x, time)`. I need to restructure the xarray so its in the `(time, y, x)` order as the original dataset. How would I go along doing this?

Here is a visual description of what's happening:

*Before:*

[image: dcube before]

Then I apply my function:

```
dcube = xr.apply_ufunc(
        bc.clip_and_normalize_percentile, 
        dcube, 
        input_core_dims=[["time"]], 
        output_core_dims=[["time"]], 
        dask = 'allowed',
        vectorize=True
    )
```

as expected `time` is moved to the last dimension:

[image: after]

How do I rearrange this so that its in the order of the original array? Are there parameters that prevent apply_ufunc from moving the dims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.10.1/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html#xarray-apply-ufunc) say that

> Core dimensions are automatically moved to the last axes of input
> variables before applying func, which facilitates using NumPy style
> generalized ufuncs

so it's unlikely that there's a way (or any parameters) to prevent that.

What I've been doing is simply call `.transpose` afterwards to restore the initial order.

In your example, that would look like:

`dcube = dcube.transpose("time", ...)`

fixing `time` to be the first dimension and shifting all other ones behind using `...`.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Was the cleanest solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would `np.swapaxes` help?

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
bb = aa.swapaxes(2,0)
print(bb.shape)
print(aa[0,1,2])
print(bb[2,1,0])
```

seems `np.einsum` can work too

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
bb = np.einsum('ijk->kji',aa)
print(bb.shape)
print(aa[0,1,2])
print(bb[2,1,0])
```